# SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: una subconsulta utilizada como expresión retornó más de un registro

Tags: sql

```
update remesa r set borrado=1 where r.envio_remesa_id=(select r.id from remesa r inner join envio_remesa er on r.envio_remesa_id=er.id where er.id=2)
```

La tabla Remesa tiene una relación N a 1 con EnvioRemesa , el tema es que quiero updatear mi bit de borrado a 1 de la tabla Remesa , pero solo actualizarse las remesas que tienen un id de envío de remesa=2.
Y me está fallando en la consulta ya que en la subconsulta ésta me devuelve 2 registros coincidentes y los intenta comparar con r.id.
¿Alguna forma de arreglar esto?

He probado también con IN:

`update remesa r set borrado=1 where r.envio_remesa_id in (select r.id from remesa r inner join envio_remesa er on r.envio_remesa_id=er.id where er.id=2`)

ahora no me salta error , pero no se actualiza los distintos registros

Comment: Que te devuelve el select en la base de datos ? Y que debería devolverte ?

Comment: @Excorpion esa subconsulta de select me devuelve múltiples registros. Lo que quiero es actualizar multiples registros , no uno solo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabo de solucionar mi problema , todo se resuelve con el operador IN para actualizar más de un registro

```
update remesa r 
set borrado=1 
where r.id
in (
    select r.id 
    from remesa r
    inner join envio_remesa er 
    on r.envio_remesa_id=er.id 
    where er.id=2)
```